# How to get text from a function into this notification alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question concerning Jquery and Javascript. I would like to use a notification alert which shows a specific text.

```
function mode(test) {
  $.n(+ test, {    
    type: "notice",
        stick: false,
        fadeSpeed : 500,
        effect : "slide"})
}
```

Now I have `<body onload="mode("some text");">`

I would like that the function mode replaces the + test with the text "some text".
I though in Javascript you put a plus and then the name of the variable?

Thanks for your help!
phpheini

Answer (score 1):

In javascript variables **may** use `$`, but not `+`. Simply using `test` should be enough.

Comment: I tried simple test before but doesnt work. Does it work the same in Jquery? Because this is Jquery not Javascript...

Comment: jQuery is not a language, its just a javascript library. There may be a problem with the *"* in your `onLoad`.